# Errors When Publishing in Angular 4 Project in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: angular, azure-devops, publish

We have a project in Visual Studio Team Services that cannot be built and is having a problem being published.  Here are the errors we are getting:

```
ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts (TaskId:55) 13:58:57.035     1>Module 
not found : error : Can't resolve 
./../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.browser.ngfactory' in 
'd:\a\3\s\Axalta.ColorSelector\ClientApp' 
[d:\a\3\s\Axalta.ColorSelector\Axalta.ColorSelector.csproj]
@ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts 6:0-95 (TaskId:55)

ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts (TaskId:55)
13:58:57.036     1>Module not found : error : Can't resolve 
'./../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.server.ngfactory' in 
'd:\a\3\s\Axalta.ColorSelector\ClientApp' 
[d:\a\3\s\Axalta.ColorSelector\Axalta.ColorSelector.csproj]
@ ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts 8:0-94 (TaskId:55)
```

Here's what's on line 8 of boot.server.ts:

```
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module.server';
```

The app.module.server.ts file physically exists but app.module.server.ngfactory does not.

I can get the project to publish locally on my computer.

I did a search and found other instances of this issue being solved by varying the parameters for the npm:

```
npm install enhanced-resolve@3.3.0
```

However, I'm running this from VSTS, which uses the following command to publish:

```
dotnet publish c:\<path> --configuration release --output c:\<path>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?  I appreciate any.

Comment: What's app.module.server.ngfactory used for? Could you reproduce this issue in a new project? You can share a simple project on the OneDrive.

Comment: I have no idea what app.module.server.ngfactory is used for.  It certainly isn't a file I created.  I'll try to reproduce this problem on a new minimal project but will need to get permissions to create a new one in VSTS.

Comment: You can share the detail build log on the OneDrive (Set syste.debug to true), then share the sample project after creating a new project.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your components **templateUrl path is correct**.If the path is wrong then deployment give you an error like above. And make sure to remove include: /ClientApp/ from the webpack.config.js

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dynamic-form',
    templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
    providers: [DynamicControlService]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The vs2017 core 2.0 angular template has a line in the webpack.config.js file:

```
{ test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
```

The `include: /ClientApp/` prevents .ts files generated during publish or release build from being processed by Webpack.

If you remove the `include: /ClientApp/` from the webpack.config.js .ts rule test it should work.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  I tried what you suggested but am still getting the same error when publishing.